# Create columns in Polars with when-then-otherwise using for loop

Tags: python, python-polars

How to make the function shorter using for loop with type of super promo (TV, YouTube, Banners) in when-then expression?

```
def add_promo_means(data: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    return data.with_columns(
        [
            pl.when(pl.col("is_TV_superpromo") == 1)
            .then(pl.col(f"mean_promo_quantity_with_TV_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks"))
            .when(pl.col("is_YouTube_superpromo") == 1)
            .then(pl.col(f"mean_promo_quantity_with_YouTube_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks"))
            .when(pl.col("is_Banners_superpromo") == 1)
            .then(pl.col(f"mean_promo_quantity_with_Banners_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks"))
.otherwise(pl.col(f"mean_promo_quantity_without_superpromo_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks"))
            .alias(f"mean_promo_sales_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks")
            for week_offset in range(1, 4)
        ]
    )
```

i tried something like

```
def add_promo_means(data: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    return data.with_columns(
        [
            pl.when(pl.col("is_TV_super_promo") == 1)
            .then(pl.col(f"promo_sales_from_{superpromo}"))
            .otherwise(pl.col(f"promo_sales"))
            .alias(f"mean_promo_sales")
            for superpromo in ['TV', 'YouTube', 'Banners' ]
        ]
    )
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you add a small example input dataframe along with the expected output? The given when/then example has specific order requirements and default value behaviour which may not be obvious at first glance. Is this intended? i.e. Is it possible for multiple superpromos to be `1` at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

If you have many possible channels (`Banners`, `YouTube`, `TV`, etc.), the following will be shorter.

```py
def mean_promo_expr(week_offset: int) -> pl.Expr:
    expr = pl.col(f"mean_promo_quantity_without_superpromo_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks")
    for channel in ["Banners", "YouTube", "TV"]:
        expr = (
            pl.when(pl.col(f"is_{channel}_superpromo") == 1)
            .then(f"mean_promo_quantity_with_{channel}_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks")
            .otherwise(expr)
        )
    return expr
```

It would be used as follows.

```py
def add_promo_means(data: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    return data.with_columns(
        mean_promo_expr(week_offset)
        .alias(f"mean_promo_sales_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks")
        for week_offset in range(1, 4)
    )
```

Alternatively, you could use [`pl.coalesce`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html).

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.coalesce(
            *[
                pl.when(pl.col(f"is_{channel}_superpromo") == 1)
                .then(f"mean_promo_quantity_with_{channel}_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks")
                for channel in ["A", "B", "C"]
            ],
            f"mean_promo_quantity_with_{channel}_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks"
        ).alias(f"mean_promo_sales_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks")
        for week_offset in range(1, 4)
    )
)
```

Comment: I think your `coalesce` option is optimal

Answer (score 2):

You can use `functools.reduce` to produce a functional-style expression:

```py
from functools import reduce

promos = ['TV', 'YouTube', 'Banners']

columns = (
    (
        pl.col(f"is_{promo}_superpromo"), 
        pl.col(f"mean_promo_quantity_with_{promo}_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks")
    )
    for promo in promos
)

c = [(
    reduce(lambda x, y: x.when(y[0] == 1).then(y[1]), columns, pl.when(False).then(None))
    .otherwise(pl.col(
        f"mean_promo_quantity_without_superpromo_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks"
    ))
    .alias(f"mean_promo_sales_0_{week_offset}_promo_weeks")
) for week_offset in range(1, 4)]
```

Comment: `pl.when(False).then(None)` can be useful as a descriptive "init" value for building when/then chains.

Comment: @jqurious good catch, I'll make an edit